# How should i split the following text with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I just used the following regex pattern `example.gsub(/[\s+\W|\d+]/, " ")` which gives me
this

`"      Beginning of Year          Mid Year       End of Year      New Year"`

What should i do to make it look like this

```
"Beginning of year", "Mid Year", "End of Year", "New Year"
```

I tried using split method and this splits all words into an array like

```
"Beginning", "of", "New", "Year"
```

hope you get the idea.

Comment: What is the output that you want? Is the whole thing a string? The form as is given is not valid Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"      Beginning of Year          Mid Year       End of Year      New Year"
.strip.split(/\s{2,}/)
# => ["Beginning of Year", "Mid Year", "End of Year", "New Year"]
```

Comment: You were close. You will be better at regex soon, I guess.

Comment: Haha.. I took `{2}`.. which is wrong.. Your one correct.. `{2,}`.